# Make an array work like a circle

Tags: c#

I'm not quite sure how to do this.

pseudocode:

```
array1 = {"a","b", "c", "d", "e","f", "g","h", "i","j"} //there might be more values.
take c
loop =>c+3 =f
       f+3 =i
       i+3 =b
       b+3 =e
......
end loop
```

I need to work this `array1` as a **circle** and find the letters adding 3 (f, i, b, e, and more).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to write the "find the letters adding 3" function by yourself like:

```
new_index = (current_index+3)%length_of_array
```

Comment: I'm still not clear........ how does multiplying the array length helps? could you clear it out a little bit?

Comment: eg: i+3=b. actually "i" is the 8 element. "b" is the 1 element. (8+3)%10=1. That way gives you the right positon.(You know % operation and array index starts from 0, right)

Comment: yes yes now ... I understand... I misunderstood at first.

Answer (score 8):

Use mod (`%`), then `index` can be any positive value and it will wrap around:

```
int index;
array1[index % array1.Length]
```

Answer (score 0):

As other answer says `%` operator is the key to implement it. Here's the implementation.

```
private string[] strings = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j" };

private IEnumerable<string> GetStringWrapped(int position)
{
    int current = position - 1;
    while (true)
    {
        yield return strings[current];
        current += position;
        current %= strings.Length;
    }
}
```

Use it as

```
void SomeMethod()
{
    var resultArray = GetStringWrapped(3).Take(5).ToArray();
    //resultArray contains c,f,i,b,e
}
```

Note `Take` is important otherwise your method will never end, it will loop forever.

Comment: I have never seen any code having `return` in the middle like you did `yield return`

Comment: @Giliweed They are called as [Iterators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscyy5s0.aspx) very powerful language feature

Answer (score 0):

We can use `%` operator to calculate circular index in the array,then we can abstract it in a class

```
class CircularList<T> : List<T>
        {
            public new T this[int index]
            {
                get { return base[index%Count]; }
                set { base[index%Count] = value; }
            }

            public T this[T item, int distance]
            {
                get
                {
                    var index = IndexOf(item);
                    return this[index + distance];
                }
                set
                {
                    var index = IndexOf(item);
                    this[index + distance] = value;
                }
            }
        }
```

usage:

```
    var arr = new CircularList<string> { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j" };
    var b = arr[8 + 2];
    var b2 = arr["i", 2];
```